# POST method with CURL

Tags: jenkins, curl

I'm trying to call parameterized jenkins job.
When i run the job manually, the build is successful (it accept the value of the parameter).
Otherwise, via CURL, the job is running, but the parameter is empty.

curl -X POST http://login:pwd@localhost:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters/build?job=test&token=tokenValue --data-urlencode json='{"parameter":[{"name":"fileName","value":"test"}]'

Comment: Could you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unquoted `&` is a special character. Everything after it is considered a separate command.

Try quoting the url as shown below.

```
curl -X POST 'http://login:pwd@localhost:8080/buildByToken/buildWithParameters/build?job=test&token=tokenValue' --data-urlencode json='{"parameter":[{"name":"fileName","value":"test"}]'
```